# How to write document.getElementsByClassName(names)[n] in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to write

```
document.getElementsByClassName("navtab")[3].classList.add("active");
```

in jquery.

**My attempt:**

```
$(".navtab")[3].addClass("active");
```

This gave an error like:

> index-page9.html:745 Uncaught TypeError: **$(...)[3].addClass** is not a function

Comment: what is the problem?? you want add class for navtab to 'active' right...

Comment: you can use `.eq(3)` or `:nth(3)`

Comment: `$(".navtab:nth(3)").addClass("active");` like this

Comment: You can wrap your selected object with `$(...)` like `$($(".navtab")[3]).addClass("active")`. And it will work.

Comment: Using a CSS selector you would have to use `:nth-child(4)` of course, as its count is not zero-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".navtab")[3]
```

actually returns a DOM element and `.addClass()` jQuery method can not be used on DOM elements. You need to use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to get `nth` index jQuery object like:

```
$(".navtab").eq(3).addClass("active");
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(".navtab").eq(3).addClass("active");
```

```css
.active { background-color: skyblue }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="navtab">List item 1</li>
  <li class="navtab">List item 2</li>
  <li class="navtab">List item 3</li>
  <li class="navtab">List item 4</li>
  <li class="navtab">List item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in jquery like this:

```
  var element = $('.navtab')[3];
  $(element).addClass("active");
```

Comment: but for every array i cant take one variable. it will increase my heap memory. anyways, thankyou for your response.

Comment: You can do it without using variable also. just replace the element with $('.navtab')[3]

Comment: that the error i have asked for i am not getting doing like that.